# Understanding Javascript Block - 2 returns?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm not quite sure what the following JS code does:

```
myApp.factory('helloWorldFromFactory', function() {
    return {
        sayHello: function() {
            return "Hello, World!"
        }
    };
});
```

The code will look famililar to those of you who use Angularjs but it's the two returns that are confusing me. I assume it is a typical technique in Javascript but one which I've not seen before.

Could someone shed a little light on this for me?

Comment: The outer function returns an object with a method, that's it.

Comment: You could search for "factory pattern". It may help you understand this in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's break this down into the different involved concepts. First, the outer call:

```
myApp.factory('helloWorldFromFactory', function() {
    // irrelevant for now
});
```

You are calling the function `factory` on `myApp`, and passing two arguments: A string `'helloWorldFromFactory'` and a function. In JavaScript, functions are first class objects: That means you can pass them around and store them in variables just like you can with numbers, strings etc. Example:

```
// Store a function into a variable myFunction
var myFunction = function(x) { return x*2; };

// Invoke the function through the variable
myFunction(5);

// Pass the function to another function
someFunction(myFunction);
```

Ok, on to the first function body (the 2nd argument to `factory()`):

```
function() {
    return {
        sayHello: // let's ignore it for now
    };
}
```

This is a function returning a JavaScript object containing a property `sayHello`. This property could be anything, but in this case, it is another function:

```
function() {
    return "Hello, world!"; 
}
```

So first, you are passing a function to `factory()`. When somebody invokes that function:

```
// hypothetical code somewhere in the framework:
var theObject = yourStoredFunction();
```

That will return the aforementioned object. Now, if some other code uses that object like this:

```
var greeting = theObject['sayHello']();
```

This will invoke the innermost function, and return the string `"Hello, world!"`.

Comment: Thanks for this in-depth response. I appreciate the effort.

Answer (score 2):

The first `return` statement returns an object literal with a property. The property is a function called `sayHello`.

A simplified version might look like this:

```
function getStuff() {
    return {
        someFunction: function() {
            return 'Hello World';
        }
    }
}
var o = getStuff();
console.log(o.someFunction());
```

Answer (score 0):

When you run zhe factory, it will give you an object:

```
{sayHello: function() {
    return "Hello, World!"
}}
```

what is the first return mean. Then the second means that is you use the object.sayHello, you it will return you a string that "Hello, World!".

Answer (score 0):

Usage example in angular terms:

```
myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope, helloWorldFromFactory) {
    $scope.helloString = helloWorldFromFactory.sayHello();
});
```